# Responsiveness of website in different resolutions using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have developed a website. The responsiveness working fine in desktop view, but it is not working fine with different resolutions.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">

    <section id="ServicesSection">

                <div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div style="background-color: #3487C2; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">

                            <div style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; color: #ffffff; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 36px; font-weight: 500; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">
                                <span class="services">Our Services</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 5px;">

                                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                                        <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                            <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 left animated fadeInLeft wow">
                                                <a href="HealthSummary.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="HealthSummary">
                                                    <div   style="background-color: #ffffff ;padding:25px;  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                        <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Wellness score or Health summary</h1>
                                                        <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div    style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 right animated fadeInRight wow">
                                                <a href="HistoricalRecords.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="HistoricalRecords">
                                                    <div  style="background-color: #ffffff;padding:25px;  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                        <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Historical records storing</h1>
                                                        <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="visible-sm clearfix"></div>


                                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                            <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 left animated fadeInLeft wow">
                                                <a href="ExpertOpinon.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="ExpertOpinon">
                                                    <div style="background-color: #ffffff;padding:25px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                        <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Sharing the data or expert opinion
                                                            <br />
                                                            (Doctors, Family members, etc..)</h1>
                                                        <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 right animated fadeInRight wow">
                                                <a href="EmergencyContact.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="EmergencyContact">
                                                    <div   style="background-color: #ffffff;padding:25px; box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                        <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Emergency contact info</h1>
                                                        <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="text-align: center;" class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                            <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 left animated fadeInLeft wow">
                                                <a href="Security.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="Security">
                                                    <div  style="background-color: #ffffff;padding:25px;  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                        <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Security</h1>
                                                        <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="margin: 5px 5px;" class="col-sm-5 right animated fadeInRight wow">
                                                <a href="Recommendations.aspx" class="ServiceClick" id="Recommendations">
                                                    <div  style="background-color: #ffffff;padding:25px;  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
                                                        <h1 style="color: #3487C2; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Recommendations</h1>
                                                        <span style="color: #3487C2; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It's easy
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>

                </div>

            </section>
        </div>
```

Here is myplunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/1WNj7bl5fqCYu30UKYlf?p=preview

I am unable to get the all boxes with same height in different resolutions.
My requirement is getting the all boxes with same height in different resolutions in all browsers.

Comment: Are you seriously using all that inline css? You're in for a world of pain keeping that up - you have padding and margin all over the place - I'd start again personally with just the basic bootstrap classes

Comment: Add some fixed height for the box. For example  add  `<div class ="box"></div>` to each boxes and say `height:250px`.   In your code why the diff height occurs is because of the diff content sizes  :) happy coding

Comment: hi, @DarrenSweeney, i am new to the beginner and i know the basics of bootstrap,please help me to complete my task.

Comment: try to practice with external css. Don't use inline css .

Comment: Why don't you try this as Bootstrap has given this built in functionality for equal heights : http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: @gopal - there are plenty of clear equal height solutions in the dup question. Clean-up your code and try those before posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need this div with same height. 
its possible by adding

```
max-height: ##px;
overflow:auto;
```

The div will have same height and according to content scroll will appear.

you can adjust the height using media query.